# Trouble with MySQL on Windows 10 (php, MySQL, MAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, bash, mamp

I'm currently learning php through Laracasts and I'm loving it so far, but I'm having trouble connecting to the MySQL database.

Since I'm using Windows 10 I have set up an Apache server through MAMP, and along with it there's a MySQL DB. In Laracasts' [The PHP Practitioner: MySQL 101](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/11) Jeffrey is using the command line to enter / customize MySQL, however, when I try to do so with Git Bash I get this message:

bash: mysql: command not found

How can I access this database and do what Jeffrey is doing at the 2:40 minute mark?

Any help with understanding this is greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The `MAMP` bundle includes `mysql` but it is not added to the `PATH` environmental variable searched by command prompt or git bash when you input your command `mysql`

In order to access the `mysql` executable included in the MAMP package, you can manually visit the folder containing the `mysql` executable.

or

What you can do is add the path of the `mysql` executable to the `PATH` environmental variable and then you will have access to `mysql` command from any folder.

Assuming your MAMP installation is in  `C:\MAMP\`

You can change directory to `C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin` using 
`cd C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin` and run `mysql` command afterwards.

Alternatively, you can add the same path `C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin` to the environmental variable `PATH` and access `mysql` from any folder.

Comment: Thank you for the fleshed out answer. How can I add the path of the mysql executable to the PATH environmental variable?

Comment: Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables

Under User variables 

Edit PATH variable and add the path C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin at the end. Make sure to separate your path from other paths by a semi-colon (;)